# Display image razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to display images on my web api that are located on the server side.
for now I have added them in my solution in visual studio (I added two to try, I specified one as embedded ressource and one as none as build action. they are directly in WebAPISolution/xxx.png not in a subfolder

In my cshtml page, I put this:

```
<div>
<p>Test image</p>
     <img id="img1" alt="Image1.png" src="@Url.Content("~/Image1.png")">
</div>
```

and on my web page it doesn't shows up.
it seems to look for it at:

> view-source:https://xx.xx.xx.xx:5001/Image1.png

and the error message is

> "can't be displayed because it contains error"

, it just doesn't find it I guess because the same with ImageXXX.png which doesn't exist return the same error
I don't get why the image doesn't shows up.

here is how is organized my solution folder
[image]

Comment: I think you need to put your image in wwwroot folder

Comment: Where are you storing your image? You would have to see the exact path of your image location and then create your path accordingly. You can store your image here in your project: `<img src="/Content/Images/Image1.png" />` and then try to render it on your View. If it displays, then you are creating your path incorrectly in your code. I think it should be something like: `@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Image1.png")`

Comment: same error with both solutions. it shows alt="Image1.png" and the source page says it look for the image in https://xx.xx.xx.xx:5001/Content/Images/Image1.png or wwwroot/Image1.png
I am storing the image in the "solution folder".

Comment: @p.deman Please don't save the image in the solution folder. That is very incorrect way to store your images. Please save your images under `Content/Images` folder of your project. If you are able to see the image, then there might be a problem with the path that you save in your database for your image.

Comment: this is what I did now after your comment. I put them in SolutionFolder/Content/Images, but it gives me the same error

Comment: @p.deman The default directory that is created is: `/Content/images`. If you stored them at:`/Content/Images` then you would explicitly need to create the `Images` folder in your `Content` directory.

Comment: I didn't have any directory Content, neither images, i had to create them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191434/discussion-between-rahul-sharma-and-p-deman).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 ) In your Startup Class you should add `app.UseStaticFiles();` within   `public void Configure()` method 
2) Put your image in the wwwroot folder 
3) add this code to your razor view `<img src="~/Image1.png"  />`

Comment: what if I can't put the image in the wwwroot folder  ?

Comment: in this case you need to add somthing like this  app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
 {
  FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"content", @"js")),
  RequestPath = new PathString("/js")
 });

Comment: source : https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/04/28/serving-static-files-outside-wwwroot-asp-net-core/

Comment: perfect ! Thanks !

Comment: Please update the answer with the correct usage of `app.UseStaticFiles()` in this case for others to see.

Comment: Thank you for suggetion, i will update the answer with the correct usage

Comment: can files be added during run time this way?

Comment: I'm not sure, but i think yes